# Android starting an intent doesn't set the action

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm working with push notifications. Receiving and displaying notifications is currently working, however the on-click event isn't acting as it should.

```
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1593;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent notificationIntent =  new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("test", "test");
        notificationIntent.setAction("load_notifications");

        PendingIntent intentNotification = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 999, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title,  body, intentNotification);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

That's how I display my notification and it also includes starting/resuming my main activity.

However, the putExtra("test", "test") and the setAction seem to have no effect if I click on a notification while I'm in the app. If my app isn't working, launching it from the notification works fine.

My onResume function at my main activity:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(this.getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("load_notifications")) {
//Do stuff
            }


    }
```

My app config is as following:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Push notifications -->

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.app.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    </application>
```

Comment: I'd try to throw in some Log outputs, to check if it doesn't get in there at all, or if it just doesn't go into your if loop.
Maybe load out the action to a variable and print it as well?

Comment: I removed the log calls for the code blocks. The activity stays as MAIN, instead of the newly set "load_notifications", and the test variable I add is just null.

Answer (score 0):

the **answer** maybe be here : [Action buttons are not shown in notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311245/action-buttons-are-not-shown-in-notification)

Notification Actions were introduced in **API 16.**

This means that you should be setting your target SDK to 16 or above.

However, only **Jelly Bean** and **above** can take advantage of the Notification Actions - make sure to test this feature on those platforms.

**NotificationCompat.Builder** takes care of generating a Notification compatible with whatever API it is running on, so keep using it if you are going to be supporting **Ice Cream Sandwich and older**. If not, simply using **Notification.Builder** will suffice (*after changing the target SDK of course*).