# Action buttons are not shown in notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to display action buttons in notification bar. Notification works but I cannot see any button . I have read Android Developer document and different examples on the Internet but I could not find any big difference with my code. I have done like following:

```
public void showNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager);     
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Intent prevIntent = new Intent(mContext, PlayAudioService.class);
    prevIntent.setAction(ACTION_PREV);
    PendingIntent piPrev = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, prevIntent, 0);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(mContext, PlayAudioService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
    PendingIntent piPlay = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, playIntent, 0);

    Intent nextIntet = new Intent(mContext, PlayAudioService.class);
    nextIntet.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
    PendingIntent piNext = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, nextIntet, 0);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setWhen(0)
                //.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
            .addAction (R.drawable.ic_previous, "Prev", piPrev)
                .addAction (R.drawable.ic_play,     "Play", piPlay)
                .addAction (R.drawable.ic_next,     "Next", piNext);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent piNotify =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext,
                0,
                notifyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(piNotify);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

In activity:

```
showNotification(this);
```

My Android target SDK version 15 and I am using latest version of support library v4. What am I missing and did not understand properly?

Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification Actions were introduced in [API 16](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#UI).

This means that you should be setting your target SDK to 16 or above.

However, only Jelly Bean and above can take advantage of the Notification Actions - make sure to test this feature on those platforms.

`NotificationCompat.Builder` takes care of generating a Notification compatible with whatever API it is running on, so keep using it if you are going to be supporting Ice Cream Sandwich and older. If not, simply using `Notification.Builder` will suffice (after changing the target SDK of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. I did not see that the API was introduced from API 16.